# Orthogonal matrices proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\upsilon _{n} $ be the set of all $n \times  n$ orthogonal matrices(for all fixed $n$).
Show that $\upsilon _{n} $ is not a subspace of $\ M _{n\times n} $. Thank you !

Additional:
Suppose $A \in \upsilon_{n}$, what are the possible values for $detA?^{11}$ and possible engenvalues for  $A?^{12}$.

I am really confused about the additional one. Thanks again.

Comment: To prove $\upsilon _{n}$ is a subspace, then you need to prove the usual conditions $A+B \in \upsilon _{n} $ and $ \alpha A \in \upsilon _{n} .$ See my hint in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Is $0\in \upsilon_n{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: how can we represent the $\upsilon_{n} $

Comment: @leaveJava I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean by geometric way to represent the  $  \upsilon_{n} $. Or we don't need it?

Answer (score 3):

The set of $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices is not closed under scalar multiplication, since for any scalar $c$, and given an orthogonal matrix $A$, we have

$$(cA)(cA)^T = c^2AA^T = c^2I$$

which isn't the identity matrix if $c \ne \pm 1$.  Or more simply, using Alex's hint, observe that the $0$ matrix is not orthogonal, but every subspace must contain $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Is the sum of two orthogonal matrices is an orthogonal matrix? Check the following example

$$ \pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}+\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}=\pmatrix{1&1 \\ 1&1 }. $$

Clearly the new matrix is not orthogonal.

Comment: @Julien: Just a minute, I'll give an example.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe that's because $\pmatrix{1/2&-1/2\\1/2&1/2}+\pmatrix{1/2&1/2\\-1/2&1/2}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ is actually orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, but the way your answer was stated, it implicitly said that it was never orthogonal. Of course, it is generically not orthogonal. But when a set obviously fails to contain $0$, why would one prove it is not a subspace otherwise?

Comment: @julien: I mean that, the sum is not an orthogonal matrix in general which is enough. It is another way to prove that the statement is false.

Comment: I know you meant "in general". I just said you did not say it. Yes that's another proof. You could also say that the orthogonal matrices for a disconnected set, so they can't form a subspace...But I don't think it would be a reasonable answer. Obviously ,the OP needs to realize that any subspace must contain $0$ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Hint to additional question: if $A$ is orthogonal, it is very easy to show $A^T A = I$.  In fact, this is equivalent to being orthogonal.  More hints: what is $\operatorname{det}(BC)$ if $B$ and $C$ are square?  What is $\operatorname{det}(A^T)$ in terms of $\operatorname{det}(A)$?

For the eigenvalues, assume $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$.  Calculate the norm squared of both sides, using $\|\mathbf{v}\|^2 = \mathbf{v}^H \mathbf{v}$.  Here "$H$" is conjugate transpose, which you need if you are looking for complex eigenvalues and not just real ones.